# How to modify and extend the gridview that using datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gridview, datatable

I have setup a dataset in c# with a datatable *"calculation"*, there is 4 datacolumn  **ID, Name, Area, Length** inside the *"calculation"*. Now I would like to extend the gridview that display the *"calculation"* as datasource, the datatable have 4 datacolumn and now i would like to display one more **Volume** in the gridview by multiply the Area and Length.

```
Calculation.Rows.Add(1, "Room", 102.32, 1312.8);
this.gridView1.GridControl.DataSource = Calculation;
```

Also I would like hide the Area and Length display in gridview, only ID, Name and Volume is show.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Sorry for overlook, I am looking the solution for winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `DataTable` you can use the `DataColumn`'s `Expression` property to get the product of “Area” and “Length” columns. The code below creates a new `DataColumn` called “Volume” where its `Expression` (third parameter) is the product of the values in columns “Area” and “Length.”

Once the column has been created, simply add it to the table. Just guessing this may be what you are looking for.

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Volume", typeof(float), "Area * Length");
Calculation.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: `DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Volume", typeof(float), "Area * Length");`
For the 3rd overload, is it possible for me create a new function and modift the data return?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes you can change the `Expression` string to any legal expression. The expression is somewhat limited but can be quite useful in certain situations. The following link is to the MSDN Documentation page for the expression property. You may find it useful. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks again, I have read through the documentation that provide by you but it seem like only limit to certain function that provide by the framework. Is there anywhere I can create a new function and call it for return certain value?

Comment: Without knowing what this function does or how it may be implemented, would be difficult to say. I will not argue, the `Expression` string is somewhat limited however if a more sophisticated filter/aggregate/expression is needed you may want to look into “sql”. Again, without more info, it is difficult to give a valid answer as to which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For the additional data I would add the data you want to display to the datatable by adding an additional column. This makes it easier to use in the grid.

For displaying a subset of columns I would suggest that you create the columns you want to see manually and either leave out the columns you don't want to see or set visibile to false.  The advantage of the latter is that you can then allow the the programmer or with a little more effort the user to choose which columns to view.

Some sample code, populating a grid with simple address data as I don't have enough information to do it with your data definition:

**Creating Table Manually**

```
        var table = new DataTable {TableName = "AddressData"};

        // Declare DataColumn and DataRow variables.

        // Create new DataColumns, set DataType, ColumnName and add to DataTable.    
        // Create Addressee column.
        var column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "Addressee" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create Address1 column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "Address1" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create Address2 column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "Address2" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create CityOrTown column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "CityOrTown" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create Country column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "Country" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create CountryId column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int64"), ColumnName = "CountryId" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create CountyOrState column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "CountyOrState" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create Postcode column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "Postcode" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create Formatted Address column.
        column = new DataColumn { DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), ColumnName = "FormattedAddress" };
        table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Once you have created the table, you can populate it however you want.  Alternatively, you could simply return the table from the database including the calculated column.

**Creating columns manually**

```
    private void Prepare()
    {
        // Set up the grid
        AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        Columns.Clear();

        AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                         {
                             AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                             DataPropertyName = "Addressee",
                             DefaultCellStyle = CellStyles.Text,
                             HeaderText = @"Addressee",
                             Name = "AddresseeColumn",
                         };

        Columns.Add(column);

        // more columns added here to suit

        // Add invisible Id column
        var idColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                           {
                               DataPropertyName = "CountryId",
                               Name = "CountryIdColumn",
                               HeaderText = @"Id",
                               Width = 0,
                               Visible = false
                           };

        Columns.Add(idColumn);

    }
```

Set the DataPropertyName for each column to the column name in the table that you would like to appear. The AutoSize setting causes any spare space in the grid to be allocated automatically to the column or columns with that setting.  If you set it on multiple columns they are automatically adjusted equally e.g. if you have 90 pixels of spare space and three columns with AutoSize set to Fill then 30 pixels will be added to each.

Note that you can also use exactly the same technique from any Enumerable of objects e.g. a List or Array of custom data objects.  In the example Addresses above you could use a list of addresses to populate the grid rather than a datatable.

If you take that option you could include the calculated value in the object and avoid the work of creating the table.  Very useful if you already have suitable objects and populate them from a database.

You have plenty of choice!

Comment: Thanks for the help.